# Why am i getting, Memory Out of Bound? is it trying to mix strings with numbers? and how can i insert a white space if thats the issue?

Tags: assembly, mips

This program is trying to get an integer from the user and then count from 1 until it reaches that number. The numbers should align on top of each other so i made the SPACE: sub responsible for inserting spaces before the numbers. I'm not sure why i'm getting the Memory out of bound error, the first possibility is that i'm loading so much into $a0 but i don't know if it's the issue.
If someone can put me in the right direction i would be thankful.

```
###### Begin Text Section ######
    .text
    .globl __start

__start:                        # execution starts here


la $0, prompt       #load address of prompt into $a0
li $v0, 4       #load call code number for printing string
syscall         #call to system to display prompt

li $v0, 5       #load call code number for reading Integer
syscall         #call to system to read integer

move $t0, $v0       #move the input to $t0 for savekeeping

add $t1, 1      #initialize $t1 = 1 as the counter
add $t2, 1      #initialize $t2 = 1 as the line counter
add $t3, 10     #initialize $t3 = 10 as the sentinel
add $t4, 1      #initialize $t4 = 1 as the space

la $a0, endl        #load address of endl into a0
li $v0, 4       #load call code for printing string
syscall         #call to system to display endl

WHILE:  bge $t1, $t0, ENDWHILE  #if $t1 >= $t0, branch to ENDWHILE
        addi $t1, $t1, 1    #increment $t1 =+1

SPACE:  bgt $t1, $t0, ESPACE    #if $t1 > $t0, branch to ESPACE
        mul $t4, $t1, 10    #$t4 = $t1 * 10
        bgt $t4, $t0, ESPACE    #if $t4 > $t0, branch to ESPACE
        la $a0, spac        #load address of space into a0
        li $v0, 4       #load call code number for printing string
        syscall         #call to system to print space
        j SPACE         #jump back to SPACE to loop again

ESPACE: move $a0, $t1       #move $t1 to $a0 for display
        li $v0, 1       #load call code number for printing integer
        syscall         #call to system to display integer

       la $a0, tab      #load address of tab into a0
       li $v0, 4        #load call code number to print string
       syscall          #call to system to Display tab


       add $t2, 1       
       beq $t2, $t3, NEWLIN 
       j WHILE          #jump back to WHILE to loop again

NEWLIN:la $a0, endl     #load address of endl into a0
       li $v0, 4        #load call code number to print string
       syscall          #call to system to Display endl

       add $t2, -10     #reinitializer $t2 = 1

       j WHILE          #jump back to WHILE to loop again

ENDWHILE:
       la $a0, endl     #load address of endl into a0
       li $v0, 4        #load call code number to print string
       syscall          #call to system to Display endl

       li $v0, 10       #load call code number for ending the program
       syscall          #call to system to end the program


###### Begin Data Section ######

    .data
prompt: .asciiz "Please enter a number to trigger Count: "  #Prompt the user 
spac: .asciiz " "       #The space that will help Align numbers
tab: .asciiz "    "     #To separate numbers from each other
endl: .asciiz "\n"      #insert new line
```

Comment: Use your debugger/simulator to pinpoint the exact instruction. Then work backwards to find the root cause. Also specify what input you used.

Comment: The `j SPACE` creates infinite loop, if it is ever reached (it is probably not). But why do you get "memory out of bound" is not clear after quick glance, use debugger to pinpoint the exact spot. But this looks to be so wrong, that if you will try to debug it, you will very likely fix several problems, it feels this was posted to SO a bit prematurely, when I'm reluctant to give it a go in MARS myself... try harder

Comment: And comments like `bgt $t1, $t0, ESPACE    #if $t1 > $t0, branch to ESPACE` are not helpful. That exactly describes what the instruction does, but doesn't add anything else. I can read that from the instruction. Rather put into comment what it was supposed to achieve like "if (x > y) end spacing" or something like that, so reviewer can then contemplate whether the instruction does help to fulfil the intent/purpose described in comment.

Answer (score 0):

it was the firs la $0, prompt. should've been $a0. 
$0 is for assembler. Thank you guys

Comment: `$0` is `$zero`, hard-wired to zero.  The register that's "for the assembler" is `$1`, aka `$at`.  http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch05s03.html